# Append variable to end of $_SESSION variable

Tags: php

I am trying to append a Number to the end of a PHP `$_SESSION` variable but for some reason the number is not appending. Here is the part of the code I am having trouble with:

```
value="'.$_SESSION["fname_'.$i.'"].'"
```

`$i` contains the number I am trying to append to the `$_SESSION` variable. Any suggestions? Thanks

```
//Loop through the number of stored in $_SESSION['management-count'] and print out that many sections
    $_SESSION['management-member-template'] = '' ;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION['management-count']; $i++) {
        $_SESSION['management-member-template'] .= '
        <li class="">
            <div class="heading-line">
                <h5>Member <span class="num">'.$i.'</span></h5>
                <a href="#" class="btn-remove"><span>Remove Member</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="text-frame">
                <p>Would you like to use a previously entered individual?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="radio-line" id="radio-'.$i.'">
                    <input type="radio" id="member_'.$i.'_1" name="member_'.$i.'" checked="checked"  />
                    <label for="member_'.$i.'_1">'.$_SESSION['legal-first-name'].' '.$_SESSION['legal-last-name'].', '.$_SESSION['legal-address'].' '.$_SESSION['legal-address-2'].', '.$_SESSION['legal-city'].', '.$_SESSION['legal-state'].' '.$_SESSION['legal-zip'].'</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio-line" id="rad-'.$i.'">
                    <input type="radio" id="member_'.$i.'_2" name="member_'.$i.'" title="new-address" />
                    <label for="member_'.$i.'_2">No, enter a new name</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="new-address hidden" id="new-address-'.$i.'">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="item">
                        <label>First Name <span>*</span></label>
                        <div class="text">
                            <input type="text" name="member['.$i.'][fname]" value="'.$_SESSION["fname_'.$i.'"].'" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <label>Last Name <span>*</span></label>
                        <div class="text">
                            <input type="text" name="member['.$i.'][lname]" value="'.$_SESSION["fname_'.$i.'"].'" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#rad-'.$i.'").click(function() {
                $("#new-address-'.$i.'").removeClass("hidden");  
            });
            $("#radio-'.$i.'").click(function() {
                $("#new-address-'.$i.'").addClass("hidden");  
            });
        });
        </script>' ;
    }
```

Comment: Try `value=$_SESSION["fname_$i"];`

Comment: @AVD this did not work either

Comment: So are you trying to append the number to the _value_ of the SESSION variable, or to the variable name itself?

Comment: @JonahBishop To the variable name itself

Comment: In that case, AVD's suggestion should work. You could try pulling that bit out like this: `$index = "fname_$i"; $value = $_SESSION[$index];`

Comment: call `start_session()` function before you read the session.

Comment: @AVD I have double checked and I was already doing that. I have other $_SESSION data displaying correctly on the page. I just cannot get this value attribute to work

Comment: What result are you getting? No value? An error? Try using var_dump to double check to ensure the item you're trying to get actually exists in the session.

Comment: @AVD I have added more code to the original question. Maybe this will help us figure it out.

Comment: @Kitsune I just did what you said and it says "NULL"

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION)` returned NULL? Then your problem is elsewhere, as there is no contents in the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: @Kitsune No, var_dump($_SESSION["fname_'.$i.'"]) returned NULL. The other $_SESSION variables are working

Comment: `"fname_'.$i.'"` will definitely not work. Try echoing that string, and you'll see it'll print out this (assuming `$i` is `5` at the time): `fname_'.5.'`.

Comment: @Kitsune You are right, it was not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is the solution:

WRONG: `value="'.$_SESSION["fname_'.$i.'"].'"`

RIGHT:  `value="'.$_SESSION["fname_".$i].'" />`